# Send custom error messages in graphql-java-servlet

Tags: java, graphql, graphql-java

I am new to GraphQL and I am using graphql-java-servlet wrapper around GraphQL API. I am not able to override GraphQLErrorHandler and my SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet always returns `Internal 500 Error` in the front end.

I am trying to wrap Custom errors in graphql servlet

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured it out by myself. We have to use `GraphQLObjectMapper` builder and add the Custom Error Wrapper which implements GraphQLErrorHandler interface and implement `processErrors(List<GraphQL> error)` Method.

```
    GraphQLObjectMapper mapper = GraphQLObjectMapper.newBuilder()
                    .withGraphQLErrorHandler(customErrorHandlerObject).build();

   SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet graphQLServlet = SimpleGraphQLHttpServlet.newBuilder(ciBridgeGraphQLSchemaProvider)
                    .withObjectMapper(mapper).build();
```